# glassfish v3 remote jboss EJB client

Tags: ejb-3.0, classpath, jboss5.x, glassfish-3

I have some interesting issue regarding calling EJB 3 stateless deployed on Jboss 5 from
Glassfish v3.

I managed to do this successfully on glassfish 2.1 and jboss 5, by packing Jboss client jars with my app, but now when I do the same thing on gf3 I get ClassNotFoundException for many of jboss classes (other then ${jboss home/client}) and I just keep adding those jars but there seems not to be an end to that..

Why gf 3 requires more jboss classes then gf2, I uses the same code!?

also how can I config gf3 to look for that jar files other then to put them in domains lib dir?

Tnx for help :)

Answer (score 1):

Howzit,

I found the same thing , in GF3 you have to add in insane amount of libraries to get a stand-alone client working , here is the list I found got my client working :

```
auto-depends.jar
deployment-common.jar
glassfish-corba-internal-api.jar    
internal-api.jar
management-api.jar
bean-validator.jar
dol.jar
glassfish-corba-newtimer.jar        
javax.ejb.jar
orb-connector.jar
common-util.jar
ejb-container.jar
glassfish-corba-omgapi.jar      
javax.jms.jar
orb-iiop.jar
config-api.jar
ejb.security.jar
glassfish-corba-orb.jar
javax.resource.jar
security.jar
config-types.jar
glassfish-api.jar
glassfish-corba-orbgeneric.jar      
javax.servlet.jar
ssl-impl.jar
config.jar
glassfish-corba-asm.jar
glassfish-naming.jar
javax.transaction.jar
transaction-internal-api.jar
connectors-internal-api.jar     
glassfish-corba-codegen.jar     
gmbal.jar
jta.jar
container-common.jar
glassfish-corba-csiv2-idl.jar       
hk2-core.jar
kernel.jar
```